# How do we tell Google's crawler to ignore all pages with a specific URL variable in it's mobile usability analysis?

Tags: google-crawlers, google-search-console

Our Google Search Console is showing several hundred 'errors' in the mobile usability section.  We are concerned about the effect these errors will have on our search ranking and are trying to address them.  However, many are at addresses that look like this:

https://oursite.com/page.cfm?forceMobile=off

We have a variable called "forceMobile" that can be appended to any URL.  If set to true it forces the user into mobile view even if they are on a desktop device.  If set to false it forces users to the desktop version of a page, even if they are on a mobile device.  So the above url should be expected not to pass mobile usability checks, as it is a desktop page.

How do we prevent Google from seeing these pages as mobile pages?  Is this something we can set in search console somewhere, or is the only solution to detect user-agents and ignore the url variable for the Google crawler?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all the `forceMobile` parameter does is override device detection, you can just stop search engines from crawling it. That will also prevent them seeing the same content twice, i.e. with and without the parameter.

I'd do this in `robots.txt` for all user-agents, but you can do it in Google Search Console under URL Parameters too.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: *forceMobile*
```

Note that [Google now has a "mobile-first" approach](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2018/03/rolling-out-mobile-first-indexing.html), i.e. they crawl with a mobile user-agent, rank based on the content shown to mobile devices, etc.

Comment: Sometimes we want a page indexed, but just want to exclude it from testing, without giving up testing for all the other pages on a site.